# Reference PCL from VBA

Tags: excel, portable-class-library, vba

Can a Portable Class Library be referenced from a VBA context such as Excel? I tried adding a reference to the DLL but it fails with "Can't add a reference to the specified file."

I have written a normal class library before (with its build settings set to expose to COM) that references a PCL and then provides wrapper methods. This is tedious and complicated, is there a better solution that would expose the PCL as-is?

Comment: I don't think you can. PCL is not exposed as COM so you can't create it as a separate ActiveX object. You still need to create a normal class library which acts as a wrapper for the .NET assemblies which are not exposed as COM/OLE objects. PCL is not a COM therefore you need to go with the normal class library as a wrapper approach.